# ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './data/databases.json'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

am trying to write json data from a file contained in model folder to another file inside data folder and the two folders are contained in server folder. but i keep on getting the error message that there is no such file directory. the code below is inside model/model.ts file and the file i want to write to is in data/databases.json and both are inside server folder. i have tried using the following path `./data/databases.json, ../data/databases.json` but still not working. the folder is `server/models/model.ts`

```
let Products = require("../data/product.json") // i was able to import from the same file can't write to it using the same path
const fs = require("fs")

const creat = (newInfo:any) => {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        let id = companyInfo.length+1
        let  value = {...newInfo,"id":id}
        companyInfo.push(value)
        fs.writeFileSync('../data/databases.json',JSON.stringify(companyInfo, null, 2))
        resolve(value)
    })
}
export {creat}
```

i have another file where i call the above function and the folder path is `server/controller/controller.ts` and below is the code

```
import {creat} from "../models/model"   // importing the function here

import http, { IncomingMessage, Server, ServerResponse } from "http";

const creatCompanyinfo = async (req:IncomingMessage,res:ServerResponse)=>{
    let body =""
   req.on("data",(chunk)=>{
       body += chunk.toString()
   })
   req.on("end",async ()=>{
      let newInfo = JSON.parse(body)
     
      let result = await creat(newInfo)
      res.setHeader("Content-Type","application/json")
      res.end(JSON.stringify(result)) 
   })
}
export {creatCompanyinfo}
```

and finally the last file that handles the routing and the path is `server/app.ts`.
below is the code

```
import http, { IncomingMessage, Server, ServerResponse } from "http";

import {creatCompanyinfo} from "./controller/controller" //importing the function here

const server: Server = http.createServer((req: IncomingMessage, res: ServerResponse) => {
 if(req.url === "/companies" && req.method==="POST"){
       creatCompanyinfo(req,res)
     }
}
```

this is the path to the json file am writting to `server/data/databases.json`

below is the file structure

```
   `server/`
        `controller/controller.ts`
        `data/databases.json`
        `model/model.ts`
        `app.ts`
```

below is the error message am getting

```
Server Running at Port 4000.....
node:fs:585
  handleErrorFromBinding(ctx);
  ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './data/databases.json'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:585:3)
    at Object.writeFileSync (node:fs:2170:35)
    at /Users/dec/Challenges/week-5-task-stanzealot/server/lib/models/model.js:28:12
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.creat (/Users/dec/Challenges/week-5-task-stanzealot/server/lib/models/model.js:24:12)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/dec/Challenges/week-5-task-stanzealot/server/lib/controller/controller.js:44:36)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:539:35)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behavior of relative path in `import()` is different from relative path in `fs` methods.

`import` path is relative to source file, but `fs` path is relative to working directory.

Try converting your path to an absolute path:

```
const path = require("path");
const aPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../data/databases.json')
fs.writeFileSync(aPath ,JSON.stringify(companyInfo, null, 2))
```

Comment: thanks for your response it solve the error problem but the data i sent did get created inside json file.. am using postman to create the data.. it is currently returning the data created in postman but is not updating into the databases.json file..

Comment: @StanleyOmeje can you log the result of JSON.stringify to see if it's working or not

Comment: i just noticed the databases.json file doesnt get updated even though am sending the right value.. the JSON.stringify is working quite well but the value doesnt get written to the databases.json file

Comment: @StanleyOmeje is it writing to the correct file. delete the file to see if it is created when your write to it

Comment: i just noticed that it automatically creates another file and write to that new file instead of updating the previous file with the data.. but i still don't know how to get it to write to that file.. thanks so much for patient so far.